# echoing data from MySQL db using fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've successfully connected to my MySQL db and fetched data using this code:

```
try {
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM persoonsinfo WHERE id = ?");
$results->bindParam(1,$_SESSION["user_id"]);
$results->execute();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "data could not be retrieved";
exit;
}
```

using the `var_dump($results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` dumps the correct row! for example:

```
array(15) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["bedrijf"]=>
string(0) ""
["titel"]=>
string(0) ""
["voorletters"]=>
string(4) "test"
["tussenvoegsel"]=>
string(0) ""
["achtervoegsel"]=>
string(0) ""
["meisjesnaam"]=>
string(0) ""
["thuis_adres"]=>
string(22) "test"
["thuis_postcode"]=>
string(7) "test"
["thuis_plaats"]=>
string(9) "test"
["thuis_land"]=>
string(0) ""
["mobiele_telefoon"]=>
string(11) "test"
["email_thuis"]=>
string(20) "test"
["geboortedatum"]=>
string(0) ""
["bsn_nummer"]=>
string(0) ""
}
```

so thats perfect, but now I'm hurting my head over how to echo data to the screen.

I created this: `$user_info = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and was expecting this `<?php echo $user_info['voorletters']; ?>` to work, but it doesn't echo anything and it's driving me crazy.

Im trying to do the `echo` in my `page-mijnawf.php' file and in that file I did:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/database.php'); ?>
```

to include the code shown above.

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

**UPDATE 01**

As requested here is my updated code. Ill post three blocks, my `database.php` (database connection part) `user-session-info.php` (a session to get the userID) and `page-mijnawf.php` (the front-end page that is visible to the user):
here is `database.php`:

```
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=contacten_db;port=8889","root","root");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Could not connect to the Database Contacten_DB";
exit;
}

try {
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM persoonsinfo WHERE id = ?");
$results->bindParam(1,$_SESSION["user_id"]);
$results->execute();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "data could not be retrieved";
exit;
}

echo "<pre>"; //For Testing only

$user_info = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($user_info);

?>
```

And `user-session-info.php`:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["user_id"] = intval(get_current_user_id());

//echo "User ID =" . " " . $_SESSION["user_id"]
?>
```

and `page-mijnawf.php` which I stripped because 99% of it's content is irrelevant to this topic:

```
<div>
  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/database.php'); ?>

  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/user-info-session.php'); ?>

  <p class="no-bottom-margin">Welkom <?php echo $user_info['voorletters']; ?> Uw Fonds: </p>

</div>
```

Notice the `<?php echo $user_info['voorletters']; ?>` in the line before the closing div in the code block right above here. That line echos nothing

Thanks for helping!

Comment: ( by the way, if you include the user-info-session.php file (which calls session_start() ) after outputting a div, you'll get an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fetch" method returns the contents from the database and then skips to the next row. If you have just one row, then calling it once for the "var_dump" will already reach the end of the result set.

Your solution: do not call `var_dump($results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`, in order to execute `$results->fetch` just once!

If you need to print the record on screen for debug, then after calling `$user_info = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` you can do `var_dump($user_info)`

Comment: Your'e right! Thanks for letting me know! However, that still leaves me with the problem that echoing does not work, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @BorisKamp can you please post your entire, updated code? Thanks

Comment: After the changes, I tried running your code (stripped down to the bare minimum) and it's working on my system. What happens if you replace `<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/database.php'); ?>` with `<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/database.php'); var_dump($user_info); ?>` ?

Comment: replacing it makes the echo command work! So it looks like it does not have the info on the page without the `var_dump` in the `page-mijnawf.php` file right? How do I fix this?

Comment: @BorisKamp then you must be doing something wrong in the rest of the page. Can you please post (maybe on pastie.org ) the whole page-mijnawf.php ?

Comment: well this is getting really embarrassing. It works now! I have no idea why because I changed everything back to what it was (code from **update 01**) after your suggestion to replace `<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/database.php'); ?>` and now it works. Im clueless, could I have 'triggered' something? no right? Anyway I'd like to thank you a lot! Im so happy it works now!

Comment: did you read my last comment before asking for the whole page? Just wondering if it's still needed, if so I'll put it online off course (-: